# Can turtlebot3_fake simulate lidar and obstacles?

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting and trying to understand the world of simulator robots and rviz etc. I am working with a TurtleBot3 and wanted to see if I could use turtlebot3_fake to actually simulate Lidar  and Obstacles. Is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268671/can-turtlebot3_fake-simulate-lidar-and-obstacles?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot3_fake package does not support the features you mentioned.

The simulate Lidar, Depth, Color camera and Obstacles require a Gazebo simulator.
These features are supported by the turtlebot3_gazebo package as described in the links below.

http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/simulation.html#gazebo-3d

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2017-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0